# How to fetch value from table keeping max,min column value using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I need to fetch all record from table by keeping its some value as max or min using MySQL. I am explaining my table and code below.

db_images:

```
id        member_id        day1       day2      images

1           241             1          1         asc.png

2           241             1          2         xzc.png

3           241             2          3         ohjy.png

4          240             1           5         asd.png
```

Here is my table.I am explaining my query below.

```
$member_id=241
$qry=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_images where member_id='".$member_id."'");
```

Here i can get 3 record from table as per condition. But i need to keep `min(day1) and max(day2)` value in each record. Means each record will contain the `day1=1 and day2=3` as per the required condition and same 3 record should fetch. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please specify the expected output? Show the expected table values.

Comment: all 3 record will fetch as per condition but `day1 and day2 value will be min and max value in each record.i.e:day1=1 and day2=3` will be present in each record.

Comment: Try this query and let me know if it works: select * from db_images where member_id='$member_id' AND (day1 = (select min(day1) from db_images where id='$member_id') OR day2 = (select max(day2) from db_images where id='$member_id'))

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a subselect.

```
select minday1, maxday2, t1.id, t2.member_id, t1.images
from (select min(day1) as minday1, max(day2) as maxday2, member_id from db_images 
group by member_id) as t2, db_images  as t1
where t2.member_id = t1.member_id and t1.member_id=$member_id
```

Comment: its giving this ` #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` error.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

[image]

The following query will do the job.

```
select id,coalesce((select min(day1) from db_images where member_id=241)) as day1,
coalesce((select max(day2) from db_images where member_id=241)) as day2,
images from db_images where member_id=241
```

Here i have used `coalesce()`.
You can read more about this function here

[Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)
[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select A.*,B.DAY_2 From 
    (Select id,member_id,images,min(day1) as DAY_1 From db_images where member_id=241 group by member_id) as A
    Inner Join
    (Select id,member_id,images,max(day2) as DAY_2 From db_images where member_id=241 group by member_id) as B
```

Try this, hopefully it will help you... if your expectation is my attached image alike.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
    SELECT * , 
    (select MIN(`day1`) from `db_images` where member_id = ".$member_id.") as minDay ,    
    (select MAX(`day2`) from `db_images` where member_id= ".$member_id.") as maxDay 
    FROM `db_images` WHERE `member_id` = ".$member_id." ;
```